# Is there a way to download chatter file IDs from the file storage?

Tags: chatter, chatter-file

is it possible to retrieve a list of file IDs of files that are in the chatter file storage?

For the time being, I am only able to download the files after retrieve the ID from the chatter posts using this endpoint "/chatter/feeds/files/me/feed-elements" 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/

I would like to see if there is any way I can directly request from the chatter file storage for a list of file IDs it has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Based on the [Chatter Collaboration datamodel](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/RelationshipsOfChatterObjects.htm) or [the Chatter Cheat sheet](http://media.developerforce.com/cheatsheets/SF_chatter_4Pg_HR.pdf) you can find out that it's the ContentDocument table you're looking for if you want to find chatter files. You can query this through SOQL like this:

```
SELECT Id,Title,createddate FROM ContentDocument
```

Using the REST API you can either use the query call

```
/services/data/v29.0/query?q=SELECT+Id,Title,createddate+FROM+ContentDocument
```

or use the ContentDocument endpoint for describe, recent items or record details

```
/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/ContentDocument   

/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/ContentDocument/record_ID
```